# Pyreadline not working on venv on python windows

Tags: python, virtualenv, readline

I'm running python 3.6 on windows 10 (though I've tried this with 3.5 as well). Pyreadline does not work.

I'm not getting an error, and on my system install (without being in a virtual env), pyreadline (and therefore tab-completion) seems to be working fine.

When using virtualenv (either usng virtualenvwrapper or just raw virtualenv.exe), no tab completion works. I've tried using easy_install instead of pip as well, no dice.

Comment: Try Anaconda. Pyreadline likely requires dependencies that are not easily supplied via pip.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I am trying to do this without anaconda. Pyreadline works without virtualenv, all I had to do was pip install pyreadline. Trying to figure out what's different in the virtualenv